# After moving App data to SD card, the data still occupy space in internal SD

Tags: sd-card

I moved all application data to the SD card but, while I was navigating the internal storage files I came across a folder of the millionaire game, holding a huge amount of data and consuming my limited internal storage. 
App info 
Millionaire 
Total                            173 MB 
App                              0.93 MB
USB storage app       23.41 MB 
Data                             60 KB 
SD card                       149 MB

Comment: 149 Mb is on your SD card, the rest must remain on the internal storage. Despite the name 'move to SD' it only  moves a portion of the appliction to the SD card.

Comment: When I checked the game path at Android/data/com.ea.monopolymillionaire_row it's 144 MB.  This directory on internal storage.

Comment: That's very odd, they way it dislays is counter intuative on some devices. It means that the total is 173, 149 of which SHOULD be on the SD card, but it may be moved onto the emulated storage, which android refers to as... "SD", which does not help. It looks to me (I'd need confirmation on this_ that 0.93 is on your EXT SD card (the actual physical card) and 149 is on the emulated / SD storage on your device. This may be the way the app was designed to be honest, and you may need root to do anything further with it. But I'd appreciate feedback from others on that.

Comment: How do I check for that? I'm new to android world :-), and do you think that root is safe and won't harm my cell?

Comment: You've already checked it, I think from above USB storage is the physical SD card, and SD is the internal sd memory. Rooting is not 100% safe, you void your warranty and it CAN brick your device. I've rooted every phone I own, but there is always that risk there and I can't recommend it without you knowing the risks and reading a lot on the topic first. I woudln't recommend it entirely.

Comment: @RossC thanks for being in, your reply gave me a real insight into the risks of rooting.  I won't do it now, as my cell is  just 1 week old. btw, thanks for your concern :-)  and sorry for my English.